# CS50 pset6 readability with python

Tags: python, cs50

I am working on the project readability. I get the numbers of words, characters, and sentences correctly; However, when I try to apply these to formula, I am getting the wrong number. I'd appreciate if anyone help me to spot my mistake.

For example, if I take this text as input: "Would you like them here or there? I would not like them here or there. I would not like them anywhere." My output, index, should be 2, but what I get is 9.

```
def main():
    text = input("Text: ")

    words = len(text.split())
    sentence = text.count('.') + text.count('!') + text.count('?')
    letter = letters(text)

    print(f"Total words: {words} \nTotal sentences: {sentence} \nTotal characters: {letter}")

    L = letter / words * 100
    S = sentence / words * 100 
    index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8
    print(round(index))


def letters(text):
    chars = 0 
    for i in range(len(text)):
    if text[i].isalpha:
        chars += 1
    return chars

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The program computes the approximate grade level for the given text by using the Coleman-Liau index. This is a project belongs to the CS50 course: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/6/readability/

Comment: Please fix the indentation.  [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: `I am getting the wrong number` You haven't explain what the expected result should be or what input is being used. You should explain to us what `get_string` is/does or provide it to us.  Please read [mre].

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I am a new user and this was my first post. I am sorry if I caused any inconveniences.

Comment: [`text[i].isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) is a method so needs `()` after it

Comment: Yes, that's the solution. I missed that, thanks a lot. I was beating myself up for hours for nothing.